# Estimating actual capacitance for aluminum electrolytic capacitor in buffer application

Tags: capacitor, buck, buffer, ripple

**Application:**
In a capacitor power buffer application it is preferable to have higher voltage over the capacitors to increase the energy density, as the energy E in a capacitor is given by $$E = \frac{1}{2}CV^2$$

The capacitor voltage should thus be above the nominal voltage for the system to get higher energy density and smaller physical volume of the buffer, which then requires an input step-up converter and an output step-down converter as to charge and discharge the buffer.

**Problem**
Now, one of the energy challenges is the switching frequency of the step-down converter, seen as a ripple current at the buffer capacitors. When the buffer is active and providing hold-up, the stated capacitance for the capacitors is effectively de-rated due to the frequency of the ripple current.

**Question**
For an aluminum electrolyte capacitor and a ripple current of 1 A @ 100 kHz, how is the actual (available) capacitance estimated?

E.g. for the Vishay 250 CRZ-V series, the capacitance vs frequency is given in the graph below. The stated capacitance is thus reduced by ~ 60% at 100 kHz for the 63 - 100 V caps.

[image: 250 CRZ-V Capacitance vs Frequency]

However, most datasheets does not provide this graph. How is the actual capacitance estimated in those cases? Is there any actions that would counter the reduction of available energy other than lowering the switching frequency?

Comment: From better datasheets. But the basic premise of the question seems wrong. Increasing the rated voltage of a capacitor requires increasing the dielectric thickness and hence its size. Where is the gain over a lower voltage cap of the same physical size and larger capacitance?

Comment: @brian He probably says thay because if you use the raw supply voltage to the cap, the additional time margin will be dictated by the minimum supply voltage the system can accept, which is probably very close to the actual supply. This could be mitigated by the stepping-up/stepping-down. I agree that simply putting a step up after the cap could be enough, though.

Comment: It's is a question of having higher rated caps to allow higher voltage than the supply voltage, as @dim points out. E.g. with a supply and system voltage at 24 V, the caps could have 80 V, but the available energy for the buffer is still unknown as long as the capacitance at the operating frequency is unknown.

Comment: I didn't go into all the ways the premise seems wrong, but another one is, a PSU reservoir capacitor doesn't store energy at the switching frequency, but predominantly at DC, so it's not clear what you're asking. Perhaps you need to post a schematic of what you mean by a "capacitor power buffer" whatever that is.